# WPF split page app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, windows

I am pretty new to WPF and I am starting my first serious app based on the C# split page app template.  My question is on the actual split page itself.  Based on the item selected  on the left-hand group, I would like to load specific content in place or in addition to where the text block is.  So on selection of the first Item on the scrollview side, it would work as it does in the default sample.  The second item selection might want to display a list in place of the text block.  The third item might display a grid and some drop-down lists.
So the idea is that each item represents some sort of tool or information.

What would be the best approach here?  I have come across recommendations for the use of ContentControl or an embedded form, but I wasn't sure that those were correct to use.  Ideally for the different tools, I would have a stand alone xaml page that I could load up in the scrollview side of the split app page.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you find that template?

Comment: Its just a standard built in project type in VS2013 - Visual C#->Store Apps-Split App (Windows)

Comment: Store Apps are not WPF apps !!

Comment: I was thinking that the question could apply to WPF, XAML, or Silverlight in general.  I don't believe that its specific to WPF or XAML unless you have a different solution to propose that is unique?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found an example that is helping - User and Custom controls:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e